# Smart GWT RollOver Canvas in List Grid fields

Tags: java, gwt, canvas, smartgwt, smartgwt-pro

Normally When we add roll over canvas in smartgwt list grid, that canvas automatically added to end of list grid row.

Sample code 
https://code.google.com/p/smartgwt/source/browse/trunk/samples/showcase/src/com/smartgwt/sample/showcase/client/grid/appearance/RollOverControlsSample.java?r=1072

Screen Shot

[image: When adding roll over canvas to grid it automatically add to end of grid]

But I want to to add this roll over canvas to Country Column.

Is there any way to do this. 
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the example code, use ListGrid.setUseCellRollOvers(true) to activate cell based rollover canvas. You can then check if the colNum is for the column of interest (i.e. the Country Column, in your case) and show the rollover only for it.